# What differential equations correspond to these solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, classical-mechanics

Given solutions from two ODE's:

$x(t)=\alpha \sin(\omega t+\phi)$

$y(t)=\alpha \omega \cos(\omega t+\phi)$

Which two ODEs correspond to each of these solutions?

**My considerations:**

Obviously, the oscillator equation must be used:

$\frac{dx}{dt^2}+\omega^2x=0$

or

$\frac{dy}{dt^2}+\omega^2y=0$

These equations provide the solution $\sin(\omega t)$. How to modify them to take into account the amplitude and phase of the sinusoidal signal?

Comment: These ODEs are linear. If you multiply a given solution by a constant, you still obtain a solution

Comment: @LorenzoPompili The equations are linear, but it is not the structure of the equations that needs to be changed, but the initial conditions. Look. General solution is: $c_1cos(\omega t)+c_2sin(\omega t)$. Having chosen the necessary initial conditions, it is possible to obtain a sinusoidal or cosine signal with a given amplitude.

Comment: Yes, that is what I have in mind. The amplitude is usually related to the initial data, not to the equation itself (again, if the ode is linear). If you are looking for solutions like those you have written, I guess the most obvious ODEs are $\ddot x+\omega^2 x=0$, $y=\dot x$. I am not sure whether I fully understand your question. It seems you somehow want alpha to appear in the ODEs, right?

Comment: @LorenzoPompili Yes, you understood correctly. It would also be nice to take the phase into account.

Comment: Well, at least one of the ODEs must be nonlinear then… Also, whatever the odes are, you somehow have to obtain a family of solutions parametrized by the initial data. What are the parameters of your solutions that you want to be dependent on the initial data? If not alpha or omega, then phi? If not phi, then how would you expect the family of all solutions to be like?

Comment: I agree with you, just until recently it seemed to me that the usual oscillator equation could be easily modified. Classical sine and cosine waves are common in linear control theory and their transfer functions are well known. What is definitely good is that we can put the signal frequency into the ODE. Since there are "pitfalls", then we can work with the initial conditions. Otherwise, I don't see how to modify the amplitude or phase. You are talking about nonlinear ODE, but I do not know of nonlinear ODE of oscillators.

Comment: Sorry, I don’t quite understand you. I would suggest to restate your question more precisely (“which odes correspond to each of these solutions?” doesn’t make any sense to me, a given function could be a solution to a multitude of ODEs)

Comment: @LorenzoPompili Thank you for your advice :) I thought about it and decided that I would work with a classical harmonic oscillator and initial conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your O.D.E *does* allow for a phase expression. First of all, the general solution is, as you say:

$$x=A\sin(\omega t)+B\cos(\omega t)$$

But now consider this:

$$\alpha\sin(\omega t+\epsilon)=\alpha\sin(\omega t)\cos(\epsilon)+\alpha\cos(\omega t)\sin(\epsilon)$$

If we write that as equivalent to the first general solution, we have:

$$A\sin(\omega t)+B\cos(\omega t)\equiv\alpha\sin(\omega t)\cos(\epsilon)+\alpha\cos(\omega t)\sin(\epsilon)\\A=\alpha\cos(\epsilon)\\B=\alpha\sin(\epsilon)$$

And so it indeed does make sense to let the solution be written in phase-amplitude form.

Furthermore:

$$A^2+B^2=\alpha^2(\cos^2(\epsilon)+\sin^2(\epsilon))=\alpha^2\\\alpha=\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\\\frac{B}{A}=\frac{\alpha\sin(\epsilon)}{\alpha\cos(\epsilon)}=\tan(\epsilon)$$

So you can completely determine the phase-amplitude form from the initial conditions.

Comment: I agree with you, just until recently it seemed to me that the usual oscillator equation could be easily modified. Classical sine and cosine waves are common in linear control theory and their transfer functions are well known. What is definitely good is that we can put the signal frequency into the ODE. Since there are "pitfalls", then we can work with the initial conditions. Otherwise, I don't see how to modify the amplitude or phase. Probably, we must find nonlinear ODE, but I do not know of nonlinear ODE of oscillators.

Comment: Well my answer just showed the solution to $x''(t)+\omega^2t=0$, a fairly simple ODE, the one you asked for @dtn

Comment: The phase and amplitude is completely determined by initial conditions... the ODE remains the same, the simple harmonic motion model

Comment: Everything is clear to me. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @dtn you're welcome. I imagine a very similar technique will give you your equation for $y=\alpha\omega\cos(\omega t+\epsilon)$